# How to make list of Functions/list that calling functions in flutter(dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new at dart and I am trying for hours to make a list that every index calling other function. and I didn't found a solution to my problem. I tried alot of things and none of them was working for me
I want to call the class "DataSearch" from the search.dart insted the text "Index 2: search". someone know how can I do that?.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'search.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static const TextStyle optionStyle =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Profile',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 2: Search',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Temp'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {
                showSearch(context: context, delegate: DataSearch());
              }),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            label: 'Search',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.lightBlue[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are calling the functions by typing `func1()`. If you simply want to store a reference to the functions, get rid of the parentheses so it's just `func1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
void func1() { 
  print("function 1 called"); 
}

void func2() { 
  print("function 2 called"); 
}

void func3() { 
  print("function 3 called"); 
}

void main() {
  final List<Function> _widgetOptions = [
    func1,
    func2,
    func3,
  ];
  
  // this prints "function 2 called", since it's the second in the list
  _widgetOptions[1]();
}
```

Comment: but my function are not wroted like that. they are a class from other file.
do you know how can I call them?

Comment: No, I cannot magically see your code. Please post your actual code in the question and we will try to help you.

Comment: I post the code so if you know how can I do that it will be great

Comment: So where is the list of functions and which function do you want in there?

Comment: what I want to do is when the user click the search button from the "BottomNavigationBarItem" it will call the DataSearch() class. so I thought to use the list "_widgetOptions" and call the functions insted the Texts widget

Comment: How to store a function with one or more args in the list? 
```Ex: final List<Function> functions = [func1(url), func2(name)]```

Comment: @VinothVino You create an anonymous fuction with zero args from your functions with arguments: `final List<Function> functions = [() => func1(url), () => func2(name)];`